# Copy image URL address + open new tab Chrome plugin?

Tags: images, chrome

I can't seem to find anything that does this.

When I take notes sometimes I make image diagrams that span 1300px wide * 2400px high and embed them into a markdown editor. I make these diagrams because sometimes the subject material I'm learning is rather complicated.

[image: screenshot]

My monitors are just 15.6" big, so it's kind of hard for me to view these images. Normally, what I do is pop open up the image (hosted on imgur) into a new tab so I can zoom in and out easily like so:

[image: screencast]

The problem I have is that I have many of these super large image diagrams in my Markdown notes, and it's kind of a pain for me to constantly open new tabs to view my image diagrams. See example:

[image: screencast]

So I have to manually "right click and copy image address" like so, and then paste it into a new tab so I can view it.

[image: screenshot]

### Question

**Is there a way to expedite this process?** Perhaps a right click context menu like "open URL image address into a new tab" in Chrome?

I can't seem to click the image as well, there must be a better way to do this? If I could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+left click into a new window that works too.

I could probably write a JavaScript Chrome plugin, but I don't really know what controls the context menu buttons and what resources I need to make it.

The only question I found similar to this [was in 2012 though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423670/chrome-extension-that-copies-image-url-on-click).

Also, I searched almost every Chrome plugin I can that might have this feature but did not find any.

The other easier solution is to just buy a vertical monitor so images would resize on height easier but I cannot utilize this solution.

Comment: oh wait I could just open image in new tab... never mind http://i.imgur.com/un3sLcs.png

Comment: If this is a solution for your case, please write an answer (and acecpt it) :)

Answer (score 1):

I just figured you don't need any plugin for that. Simply open the image in a new tab:

[image: screenshot]